# jquery set line-height equal to parent container height

Tags: jquery

I need to set the line-height dynamically for an h4 based on how high the containing div is. Height will change based on content and screensize.

html

```
  <div class="col-sm-6 left">
    <div>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
```

jquery

```
// set line height of h4 to height of containing div
var divHeight = $('.left').height();

$('.left h4').css('line-height',divHeight);
```

This isn't working. I've tried a couple of different ways to pass divHeight through but it doesn't work.

Updated with a bootply http://www.bootply.com/9fOHaR0iv0

Comment: are you sure line height is what you want? line height has nothing to do with font size if thats what you meant...

Comment: Yes I need line height in order to vertically center the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following your update with bootply link, it seems you have pictures load in your div which define the div's height.

you have run your code inside `$(document).ready()` which executes once DOM loads, when in fact you need to wait until all the images load and not the DOM.

you should change your

`$(document).ready()`

to:

`$(window).load()`

it will make sure that all images are loaded, and then you will get the correct height.

here is your fixed code: <kbd>[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/bAkIzAwXoS)</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the 'px'

`$('.left h4').css('line-height',divHeight + 'px');`

Comment: works without 'px'. adding 'px' makes it stop working.

Comment: in what browser did you try this?

Comment: @a wolf, yep now everything makes sense, this answer makes sense if em is used by default.

Comment: @Banana That's said, regarding your comment under OP's question, still not sure line-height is what OP is looking for

Comment: I did this http://jsfiddle.net/U3VD3/ and it works, also I'm using the same version of chrome

Comment: with or without + 'px' it's not working for me. When I check dev tools the height for "left" is 225.40625px but the h4 height gets set to 1px. Any idea why?

Comment: height and line height are different things, have a look at the fiddle 2 comments above,it seems to work well