# Which magic CSS causes the difference of text-vertical-align between <button> and <div>?

Tags: html, css

I found that the text inside of `<button>` is automatically vertically centered, while text inside of `<div>` is top aligned.

I tried to find out which CSS rule made the difference but failed.

```css
div,
button {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>text text</div>
<button>text text</button>

<div>text text text text</div>
<button>text text text text</button>

<div>text text text text text text</div>
<button>text text text text text text</button>
```

As for the above example, comparing all the computed CSS rules from Chrome, I could only find one different pair -- `align-items: stretch` for `<div>` while `align-items: flex-start` for `<button>`.

But assigning `align-items: flex-start` doesn't help. So I got totally confused.

what confused me is that **the text-vertical-alignment is different between `<div>` and `<button>` even if you set all the CSS rules with the same corresponding value.** In other words, with the same CSS rules, `<div>` and `<button>` behave differently. Why?

What is the magic under the hood?

---

I can vertically center text inside of `<div>` (example below). I'm just curious about what causes the difference between the text-vertical-alignment.

Maybe it's not caused by a particular CSS rule, but because the layout algorithms for the two elements are different in browser?

```css
div,
button {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
}

div { /* basic CSS rules to button-fy  */
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Magic */
div, button {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
          transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div><span>text text</span></div>
<button>text text</button>

<div><span>text text text text</span></div>
<button>text text text text</button>

<div><span>text text text text text text</span></div>
<button>text text text text text text</button>
```

Comment: An alternative, if you need the div to be `display:block` is to set  `line-height:4em`

Comment: Hi Moon, not sure what you still require, the root cause is the `vertical-align`ment of the elements. When you display it as `inline-block`, it becomes the `baseline` vertical alignment, which is different for differently heighted elements. Let me know if I need to clarify more!

Comment: I believe the question is, **despite `height`, `vertical-align`, and every other CSS property seemingly being the same for both elements, _why_ are the positions different in this case?** OP is not necessarily asking _which_ set of CSS properties would make them behave similarly - that is already known.

Comment: you may find an answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764600/what-makes-the-text-on-a-button-element-vertically-centered

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you look at Chrome source code you can kind of see how it works, at least for Chrome. It seems there's an anonymous flex box created with a specific style applied. It's not that straightforward — at least not for me — but still, you can deduce what style is applied to this anonymous element. You can see here:
https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/layout/LayoutButton.cpp?sq=package:chromium

The interesting part:

```
void LayoutButton::updateAnonymousChildStyle(const LayoutObject& child,
                                             ComputedStyle& childStyle) const {
  ASSERT(!m_inner || &child == m_inner);

  childStyle.setFlexGrow(1.0f);
  // min-width: 0; is needed for correct shrinking.
  childStyle.setMinWidth(Length(0, Fixed));
  // Use margin:auto instead of align-items:center to get safe centering, i.e.
  // when the content overflows, treat it the same as align-items: flex-start.
  childStyle.setMarginTop(Length());
  childStyle.setMarginBottom(Length());
  childStyle.setFlexDirection(style()->flexDirection());
  childStyle.setJustifyContent(style()->justifyContent());
  childStyle.setFlexWrap(style()->flexWrap());
  // TODO (lajava): An anonymous box must not be used to resolve children's auto
  // values.
  childStyle.setAlignItems(style()->alignItems());
  childStyle.setAlignContent(style()->alignContent());
}
```

This gives something like this :

```
div span {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center; 
  min-width: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

Then you just need to wrap the div content in that span and apply the style. All these rules are probably not all necessary or accurate but the result seems ok:

```css
div,
button {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  float: left;
}
div span {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 0px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  cursor: default;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div><span>text text</span>
</div>
<button>text text</button>

<div><span>text text text text</span>
</div>
<button>text text text text</button>

<div><span>text text text text text text</span>
</div>
<button>text text text text text text</button>
```

Comment: I love this answer. The question specifically asks "under the hood" and this not only explains it using the code under the hood, it also includes a better solution (flexbox) of how to center text than the current high rating answer. Kudos!

Comment: Thanks. I pick this as answer because the most important thing I want to know is not how to use CSS solve the issue, but how the code under the hood affects the layout. This answer gives perfect explanation and the flex solution is a plus.

Answer (score 16):

Since you are using `inline-block`, you need to use `vertical-align` as the default is `baseline`:

**Magic CSS:**

```
vertical-align: middle;
```

The above will fix it:

```css
div,
button {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<button>text</button>
```

And for the text inside the `div` to be centred, you need to use `line-height` to the `height` of the `div`.

**Magic CSS:**

```
line-height: 4em;
```

```css
div,
button {
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  margin: 1em;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-family: Arial;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 4em;
}

div {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: default;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div>text</div>
<button>text</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried that. But the main difference I care is the vertical alignment of the text inside of `<div>`/`<button>`. The text inside of your `<div>` is top aligned still.

Comment: @Moon Check both the snippets boss. `:)` I gave it specifically. LoL, don't say you tried that without checking the second snippet.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not satisfied. `line-height` is hard-coded in your code. Given that both the default `vertical-align` for these two tags are `baseline`, why would they behave differently?

Comment: I updated my example code snippet. Multi-line text with default line-height. What would you do?

Comment: @Moon This solution will not suit for multiline text. You want the text to be in middle aligned? You can use `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: middle;` - crappy fix though.

Comment: @Moon Hi Moon, not sure what you still require, the root cause is the `vertical-align`ment of the elements. When you display it as `inline-block`, it becomes the `baseline` vertical alignment, which is different for differently heighted elements. Let me know if I need to clarify more!

Answer (score 1):

I think you may consider one of the following solutions

**Solution #1**

Add these to the div style

display: table-cell;

vertical-align: middle;

If you still need to use inline-block display, you can use nested div, the parent div will be displayed as (inline-block), the child div will be displayed as (table-cell) and that's where you middle the text.

**Solution #2**

You can set the div padding and line height dynamically using jQuery .. and this will be done on the run time, and will be adjusted based on the size of the content inside the div. you can check this question [jquery set line-height equal to parent container height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24065122/jquery-set-line-height-equal-to-parent-container-height)