# CSS: Vertical align text of anchor and button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my buttons and anchors look the same. But when i have long text inside an button / anchor it should break and display the text vertical centered. When there is enough space the text should also be centered.

In order to get the text centered and not overflowing when the text breaks i set the `line-height:1` also i set `vertical-align:1` and of course i had to set `white-space: normal` otherwise the text would not break and the button would overflow.

Now i have following problem (tested with chrome): when the text is a single line it will not be centered anymore inside the anchor tag... furthermore **I do not want to change the DOM** (wrapping the text inside span etc..)

Can you tell my why the button behaves different than the anchor? I already checked all styles within the chrome inspector (computed -> show all). I also checked the `:before` and `:after` styles.

```css
.btn{
  white-space: normal !important;
  height: 45px !important;
  vertical-align: middle !important;
  line-height: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">test loooooooooooooooooooongstring<a>
    <br /><br />
    <button class="btn btn-default">test loooooooooooooooooooongstring</button>
  </div>
</div>
    
<br /><br /><br />
    
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    Should be centered!!
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">test string<a>
     <br /><br />
    <button class="btn btn-default">test string</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you remove fixed height from .btn, you can get vertically aligned text for both

Comment: yeah but i want buttons with height 45px (customer request)

Comment: ok, if so did you tried display:table-cell for .btn ?

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957592/which-magic-css-causes-the-difference-of-text-vertical-align-between-button-an

Comment: yeah but then i need a display:table as parent. and therefore i would have to change the DOM at every occurrence of my custom button

Comment: no not a duplicate... because i have multiline text and because of that i can´t just set the line-height to the height of the button

Comment: @warch you don't need to add `display: table` on parent. Just add `display: table-cell` in styles of `.btn-default`. And check for all browsers to make sure that it behaves similar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
.btn{
   display: inline-flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

**You Should change here**
// you need to change 'col-xs-2' to col-xs-12 or upper because when your text is so long, the button extend extra from col-xs-2 width. do you understand?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
     <a href="#" class="btn btn-default">test loooooooooooooooooooongstring<a>
    <br /><br />
   <button class="btn btn-default">test loooooooooooooooooooongstring</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i did this on purpose because i wanted to show how it looks when it breaks