# How can you represent the difference between the HTML anchor(with inline-block) and the button as CSS properties?

Tags: html, css

The HTML anchor(with the *inline-block* mode) and button aligns their contents vertically in different ways, as in the following example.

```html
AAA
<a href='#' style='display:inline-block;width:100px;height:100px;text-align:center;background:green'>
    <span style='background:red'>BBB</span>
</a>
CCC

<br><br>

AAA
<button style='width:100px;height:100px;background:green'>
    <span style='background:red'>BBB</span>
</button>
CCC
```

I compared computed CSS properties of the anchor and button in the developer mode of Chrome, but could not find any properties related to the difference.

Is it possible to make an anchor to behave like a button by applying CSS properties, while keeping the *inline-block* mode? (I know it's possible by using the *inline-flex* mode.)

And if it's not possible, does that mean there are some hidden layout rules in the HTML rendering that cannot be controlled by CSS?

Comment: inline-flex will give the same behavior as inline-block from an outside perspective

Answer (score 1):

You can consider `inline-flex` to keep the same behavior and then simply center the content

```html
AAA
<a href='#' style='display:inline-flex;align-items:center;justify-content:center;width:100px;height:100px;text-align:center;background:green'>
    <span style='background:red'>BBB</span>
</a>
CCC

<br><br>

AAA
<button style='width:100px;height:100px;background:green'>
    <span style='background:red'>BBB</span>
</button>
CCC
```

Related:

[Which magic CSS causes the difference of text-vertical-align between <button> and <div>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39957592/8620333)

[What makes the text on a <button> element vertically centered?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15764600/8620333)

Comment: Cubed Eye's answer on the first link solves what I wondered. Can you edit the answer to clearly mention the impossibility and summarize Cubed Eye's answer, for other readers?